# Displaying only 1 error per field in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with email as one of its attributes. It has the following validation:

```
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

When the user submits the form with an empty empty email, I get the following 2 errors:

- Email can't be blank
- Email is invalid

How can I display only the first error message related to a field in such a scenario?

I'm retrieving the error messages associated with the object by doing:

```
@object.errors.full_messages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that very easy with this line:

```
<%= @object.errors.full_messages.first if @object.errors.any? %>
```

Just replace with your object instance. If you want to use with just one field then there is this method

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages_for:

```
object.errors.full_messages_for(:email)
```

This will get you specific error for single field

EDIT:

if you have a lot of fields:

```
<% @object.errors.each do |attr, msg| %>
  <%= "#{attr} #{msg}" if @object.errors[attr].first == msg %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do this in more scalable way? For example, if my form has 10 fields, I don't want to individually extract the first error associated with each field.

Comment: I edited the question - you can customize the output if need inside ""